# Getting older (any) Firefox version

Tags: browsers

Where to get installer for older Firefox version?

For testing, I often need particular version and language mutation of particular browser, and Google often leads to sites that tend to either serve FF in my local language, or only in en_US.

Where is some nice directory of every version and every language build ever made?

Answer (score 12):

One of the nicest directories is [official FTP](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/).

It's

- official
- organized per OS/arch
- organized per version (including Beta, Aurora and Nightly builds)
- organized per language

However, the FTP directory doesn't have as many mirrors as the [official Releases server](http://releases.mozilla.org/). Therefore, the FTP directory is great, but if you're going to be downloading many of the release installers or linking to them (thereby generating a lot of traffic), you want to use the Releases server, to avoid putting tons of pressure on the FTP directory.

Comment: @strugee Thanks for improving the answer. Could you point us to list of mirrors?

Answer (score 2):

I was going to mention http://www.oldapps.com/category/browsers

But for Firefox-specific needs, the official FTP site is best.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative way to get a specific browser version - use [`browserstack`](http://www.browserstack.com/) service. It can fire up almost any browser on [almost any operating system](http://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms?product=live).

You can also run your selenium tests on `browserstack`, see [`Selenium Cloud Testing`](https://www.browserstack.com/automate).

Answer (score 1):

We use [Utilu](http://utilu.com/) for Firefox and IE versions. Not only does it have the old versions, but also the latest overnight and beta builds too.

The thing I particularly like about Utilu is that each version is standalone, and so you don't have to install and re-install when you need to do some compatibility testing.